Cursor doesnt work upon booting Ubuntu
I recently downloaded ubuntu and there are a lot of bugs, but one that started happening recently is when I boot Ubuntu, the mouse doesn't work at all for some reason. The cursor is displayed, but it's stuck near the bottom right corner of the screen, and cannot be moved or clicked at all.
I know it's not a problem of the mouse, as well, because it works fine when I'm on Windows. My mouse is Logitech, so I'm unable to install GHub because Linux doesn't support it, however the mouse WAS working until about 2 days ago.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Your graphics processing unit may be going bad. This would make everything related to graphics laggy/freezing.
